# Can I have multiple graphs in the same place in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of graphs based on a table. Instead of having a long list of graphs, is there a way to display these graphs all in the same space, but change between them?

And to clarify, I don't want to plot the data on one graph. They are completely different and have wildly different values that would look awful on the same graph. I want to click a button and switch data *and* units, similar to how the interactive graphs work.

Answer (score 1):

You could create different pages. I cannot show you any screen shots right now, but you should be able to find it by clicking "help" and searching new sheet.